# How can I fix this VSCode "Start Debugging" Error?

Tags: html, visual-studio

I have 0 experience with this IDE, so I don't know where to start to fix this.

I was trying to run a .html file and at some point, the IDE stopped working and gave me this error. I've been researching but nothing really helps so far.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIoN4.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJCxn.jpg

There are both the regular error that I get every time I run any program and my launch.json file that the error tells me to "Fix"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please type in the text of the error message you are getting instead of adding a blurred image

Comment: Sure. Can't find Nose,js binary "node": path does not exist. Make suer Node.js is installed and in your PATH, or set the 'runtimeExecutable' in your launch.json